# How to remove Unicode replacement character from Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When loading data to Snowflake using the COPY INTO command, there is an parameter called: REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS.  According to the documentation, if this is set to TRUE, then any invalid UTF-8 characters are replaced with a Unicode replacement character which looks like this (�)

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-csv

My question is, how can I remove this character from data in my table?  I have tried to use REGEXP_REPLACE but have been unable to figure out the right pattern to use.

Here is an example of what the data looks like:

[image: Unicode Replacement Character]

Notice how the LENGTH function doesn't even register that the character is there since it says there are 7 characters when there are clearly 8.

Any advice on what Snowflake SQL function to use to remove these characters would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `REPLACE(EXAMPLE,UNICODE(65533))`? Should work, but I'm not able to test that theory at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive back-and-forth with Snowflake support, we finally settled on creating our own javascript function to cleanse non-ascii characters including this unicode replacement character.

What made this challenging is that the unicode replacement character that Snowflake adds does not itself appear to be a valid character which makes it hard to remove.

The function below is the only thing we found that reliably works.  It is also super fast:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADMIN.DESIGN.REPLACE_NON_ASCII("input" varchar, "replacement" varchar )
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE JavaScript
AS
$$

//This function is used to cleanse non ascii characters out of data included corrupt non-unicode characters

var output = "";
if (input == undefined){
    return input
}
else {
  for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
      if (input.charCodeAt(i) >= 32 && input.charCodeAt(i) <= 127) {
          output += input.charAt(i);
      }
      else {
          output += replacement
      }
  }
  return output
}
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

The "unicode replacement character" is `\uFFFD` so replacing that with `''` should work

```
select replace('asdf�', '\uFFFD', '');
--Returns: asdf
```